# Cyborg prosthetics going wrong and violent

Tags: story-identification, cyborg

I remember seeing an ad for a TV show a few years ago about people with Cybernetic or Cyborg limbs. Something happened and they went crazy and made the people who had them act violently, so I think the government sent them all away to another part of the world or just put very strict laws on them. I could have sworn that I saw this somewhere, maybe on Netflix?

Comment: Similar plot to "The Terminal Man" movie by Michael Crichton, which was on TV frequently until about the mid-80s when restrictions on levels of violence removed it.

Comment: Was this live-action, or animated? If it was computer-animated, it sounds like it may actually be a video game, Deus Ex: Mankind Divided.